# Sort array with weekday keys by weekday order

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I want to sort array with weekday keys in the order of the week, like this: Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, Saturday.

Given input like this:

```
Array
(
  [Thursday] => 8
  [Friday] => 7
  [Monday] => 9
  [Tuesday] => 12
  [Wednesday] => 8
  [Saturday] => 17
)
```

I want a result like this:

```
Array
(
  [Monday] => 9
  [Tuesday] => 12
  [Wednesday] => 8
  [thusday] => 8
  [friday] => 7
  [Saturday] => 17
)
```

Please Help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The following code does not make use of any sorting functions .. In other words.. a sort is unnecessary in this context.

```
<?php

//Your actual array...
$arr=Array (
    'Thursday' => 8,
    'Friday' => 7,
    'Monday' => 9,
    'Tuesday' => 12,
    'Wednesday' => 8,
    'Saturday' => 17
);

//This is the template array.. Changing this alters the output
$arr2=array('Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday');

//A simple loop that traverses all elements of the template...
foreach($arr2 as $v)
{
    //If the value in the template exists as a key in the actual array.. (condition)
    if(array_key_exists($v,$arr))
    {
        $arr4[$v]=$arr[$v]; //The value is assigned to the new array and the key of the actual array is assigned as a value to the new array
    }
}

//prints the new array
print_r($arr4);
```

**`OUTPUT :`**

```
Array
(
    [Monday] => 9
    [Tuesday] => 12
    [Wednesday] => 8
    [Thursday] => 8
    [Friday] => 7
    [Saturday] => 17
)
```

Comment: @ChiragPipariya, Modified the new code and removed unnecessary functions also added comments so you can understand what is being done on the code.

Answer (score 5):

Use [`uksort`.](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.uksort.php)  Here's one way:

```
$week_order = array_flip(array('Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday',
                               'Friday', 'Saturday'));

$data = array('Thursday' => 8, 'Friday' => 7, 'Monday' => 9, 'Tuesday' => 12,
               'Wednesday' => 8, 'Saturday' => 17);

uksort($data, 
  function($a, $b) use ($week_order) { return $week_order[$a] - $week_order[$b]; });

print_r($data);
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of ways to do this, but it is fairly simple with [`array_merge`](https://www.php.net/array_merge)

```
$d = array(
  'Sunday' => '',
  'Monday' => '',
  'Tuesday' => '',
  'Wednesday' => '',
  'Thursday' => '',
  'Friday' => '',
  'Saturday' => '',
);
$n = array
  (
  'Thursday' => 8,
  'Friday' => 7,
  'Monday' => 9,
  'Tuesday' => 12,
  'Wednesday' => 8,
  'Saturday' => 17,
);
var_dump(array_filter(array_merge($d,$n)));
```

[`array_filter`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) removes the empty values giving you this:

```
array(6) {
  ["Monday"]=>
  int(9)
  ["Tuesday"]=>
  int(12)
  ["Wednesday"]=>
  int(8)
  ["Thursday"]=>
  int(8)
  ["Friday"]=>
  int(7)
  ["Saturday"]=>
  int(17)
}
```

Without it, you would have this:

```
array(7) {
  ["Sunday"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["Monday"]=>
  int(9)
  ["Tuesday"]=>
  int(12)
  ["Wednesday"]=>
  int(8)
  ["Thursday"]=>
  int(8)
  ["Friday"]=>
  int(7)
  ["Saturday"]=>
  int(17)
}
```

Note the empty value for "Sunday"

It can also be done with a simple loop:

```
$d = array(
  'Sunday',
  'Monday',
  'Tuesday',
  'Wednesday',
  'Thursday',
  'Friday',
  'Saturday',
);
$n = array (
  'Thursday' => 8,
  'Friday' => 7,
  'Monday' => 9,
  'Tuesday' => 12,
  'Wednesday' => 8,
  'Saturday' => 17,
);
$sorted = array();
foreach ($d as $k) {
  if (isset($n[$k])) {
    $sorted[$k] = $n[$k];
  }
}
var_dump($sorted);
```