# Sorting an array of weekdays time combination in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have an array in the form:

```
    $sortme = array(
        'Monday 10:00',
        'Friday 12:00',
        'Tuesday 14:00',
        'Monday 08:00',
        'Wednesday 11:00',
    );
```

The number of elements is unknown (so I couldn't use the uksort approach with a reference array for the order of weekdays [as Mark suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21718653/sort-array-with-weekday-keys-by-weekday-order)). I want the result to be sorted chronologically and always starting with Monday like this:

```
    $sorted = array(
        'Monday 08:00',
        'Monday 10:00',
        'Tuesday 14:00',
        'Wednesday 11:00',
        'Friday 12:00',
    );
```

Is there an elegant way to do it without resorting to transform the array to a two-dimensional one and iterating? This would have been my only idea so far.

Comment: The hard part is telling PHP they are all days of the same week. You have no context for when those days are so PHP will use the *next* available day. So sorting this will only work on weekends. http://codepad.viper-7.com/vBBeFt. But this code can be modified to be smarter. Hope it helps.

Comment: What do you mean by "elegant". I don't think a 1 liner is doable but a 10 line function would work.

Comment: Michael, perhaps "best practice approach" would be more fitting than elegant.

Comment: @MichaelVilleneuve: Challenge accepted (1 liner).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `usort` function in PHP, which will do sorting using user-specified comparison function. The code below is probably not the most efficient, but it'll produce the correct result.

```
$sortme = array(
        'Monday 10:00',
        'Friday 12:00',
        'Tuesday 14:00',
        'Monday 08:00',
        'Wednesday 11:00',
    );

usort($sortme, function($a, $b) { return strcmp(date('N H:i', strtotime($a)), date('N H:i', strtotime($b))); });
print_r($sortme);
```

Comment: Indeed, that works nicely. Thanks for the quick reply. I'll mark this the correct answer unless there is a more effective solution. Anyways, by far better than my initial thought of splitting the day and time and sorting :-)

Comment: @Stephan No problem. You may find some optimisation in the `cmp` function - but the general idea will be the same - define the comparison function and call `usort` with it.

Comment: Why the `$days` array when date can give you the same thing?

Comment: @Stephan I modified my answer - to turn it into a very simple one-liner

Answer (score 1):

I was trying a one-liner with `array_multisort` and `array_map` or `call_user_func_array` but my brain is fried.  Try this:

```
foreach($sortme as $val) {
    $sorter[] = date('N H:i', strtotime($val));
}
array_multisort($sorter, SORT_ASC, $sortme);
```

**EDIT**: One-long-liner:

```
array_multisort(array_map(function($v){return date('N H:i',strtotime($v));}, $sortme), SORT_ASC, $sortme);
```

[DEMO](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/899065f6428fba7b95bccee8a7e36fa8af971833)

```
array_multisort(
                array_map(
                          function($v){
                              return date('N H:i',strtotime($v));
                          }, 
                            $sortme),
                                     SORT_ASC, $sortme);
```

Comment: Quite impressive, but in favor of code maintainability I think I stick with multiple lines of code for now ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```
$sortme = array(
    'Monday 10:00',
    'Friday 12:00',
    'Tuesday 14:00',
    'Monday 08:00',
    'Wednesday 11:00',
);

$sorted = array();

// Add the day of week in the begining of the string
for($i = 0; $i < count($sortme); $i++){

    $day = explode(' ', $sortme[$i]);
    @$dayNumber = date('w', strtotime($day[0]));        

    array_push($sorted, $dayNumber . $day[0] . ' '. $day[1]);   

}

// Sort the array
asort($sorted);

// Remove the day of week
for($i = 0; $i < count($sorted); $i++){
    $sorted[$i] = substr($sorted[$i], 1);
}

var_dump($sorted);
```

Answer (score 0):

You just have to convert the array items into something that *is* sortable:

```
function sortTimes(array $dates) {
    $base = strtotime('next monday 00:00');
    usort($dates, function($a, $b) use ($base) {
        return strtotime($a, $base) - strtotime($b, $base);
    });
    return $dates;
}
```